# Stay on hover when moving to hovered content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs (#one, #two) - one is on the upper level and the other one is contained in many others (here is only one, for example):

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="one"></div>
</body>
```

Both divs positioned absolute near each other. #one is hidden with JQuery `.hide()`. 
When I hover over #two I show #one with JQuery `.show()`. 
Is there any way to move from #two to #one so the hover effect stays and #one is not hidden until I hover out from both of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5ZtP/ - for illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both `"#one"` and `"#two"` by using this selector `$('#two,#one');`

```
$('#one').hide();
$('#two,#one').hover(
    function() {
        $('#one').show();
    },
    function() {
       $('#one').hide(); 
    }
);
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Q5ZtP/1/

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to put `one` inside `two`. The bubbling effect will cause you to still be hovering over `two` even when you're hovering over `one`.

```
<div id="two"><div id="one"></div></div>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q5ZtP/2/

Comment: I like this nesting approach.  It's similar to using lists for drop down menus with the parent `li` continuing to be active while the child `li`'s are hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$('#two').hover(...)
```

to

```
$('#one, #two').hover(...)
```

in your code.